# How to make a text box, with a square in front of the text, with link

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm pretty new at this, and i really needs some help!
I have tried and tried. But never come to the finish line.
I'm trying to make a text box to the left side of the page.
I want three text boxes, next to eachother,with a small box to the left of the text. This i want inside the text box.
[image]

I really hope someone could help me, i don't understand everything, because i'm new at this.

I have tried alot of different codes. Can someone please help me.

Comment: Since you've added the tag `wordpress` and someone else provided some HTML/CSS already: you probably want the code added to the sidebar inside a widget. Are you using a template or building your own?

Comment: I'm using a template, but i just go inside the css style sheet, and put in the codes for this or something else i need, to custom some small thing, some places on the site. And i just needs some of the boxes, in some of the pages. And i just got really stucked. I'm in the learning process. So i'm really happy for every help i can get. :) Yes i tagged wordpress, because i'm working with it :) I just have to put the css in. and use the customed html applikasjon. I love doing this it's real fun :) So thank's to everybody that helps me. I'm also new at this site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.btn{
display:inline-block;
background:#ddd;
padding:6px;
}
span{
position:relative;
padding-left:25px;
}
span:before{
position:absolute;
content:"";
width:18px;
height:18px;
top:0px;
left:0;
background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-textboxes">

<a class="btn"><span>Text</span></a>
<a class="btn"><span>Text</span></a>
<a class="btn"><span>Text</span></a>

</div>
```

This is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You mean Like this?

```css
div{
  width: 50px;
  
  /* Just visual */
  border: solid black 1px;
}

#one{
  float: left;
}
#two{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
#three{
  margin-left: 115px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <p>one</p>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <p>two</p>
</div>
<div id="three">
  <p>three</p>
</div>
```

You can just add the boxes to it if you want, i would recommend you to do that with [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/). 
 It's easy to use and there are a ton of nice Icons and Tutorials out there.

Comment: Not like that i'm sorry. It was more like the answar one down :) Thank you for answer me.